# Mailman for lists with an external mail server for mailboxes

Tags: postfix, email-server, mx-record, mailman

I learned how to setup Mailman with Postfix for a domain like "@lists.domain.com
But for regular mailboxes for this domain, I'd like to use the free email hosting solution of the hosting company (gandi). They also offer the SMTP service.

Given that there can be only one MX record for a domain, what is the best way to combine : mailboxes on the free email hosting service and lists managed by mailman ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subdomains are the solution. A subdomain can have an individual MX record.

Comment: thx, with registrar offering web interface for configuring DNS it's easy to forget what we CAN do...